# Принцип работы BitTorrent

Tags: python-3.6, torrent

Если описывать просто, то протокол BT работает так:

1. Получаем список пиров
2. Запрашиваем у пиров 'кусочки' файла

Можете просто описать, каким образом этот протокол работает на уровне запросов / сокетов. Т.е. какие запросы, с какими параметрами нужно сделать, какой ответ нужно получить, как его обработать, чтобы получить один единственный 'кусочек' (piece)? В итоговом варианте мне нужно получать эти кусочки один за другим и обрабатывать поочерёдно. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Если у вас стоит практическая задача скачать файл через торрент, почему бы не взять какой-нибудь готовый торрент-клиент на Python? Даже если они вам по какой-то причине не подходят, всегда можно посмотреть их внутреннее устройство и запросы/сокеты

Comment: Большинство готовых bittorent-клиентов написаны на python2.x или выдают ошибки при попытке скачать файл, а внутреннее устройство не даёт того представления о работе протокола, которое я хотел получить здесь. Если проще, внутренний код клиентов нечитаемый.